# Tengo: frío, años, enojo. Español "posesivo"?

Tags: verbos, español-neutral

Hace mucho tengo una pregunta:
En español usamos el verbo TENER para todo,
- Tengo 30 años de edad
- Tengo frío/calor
- Tengo sueño
- Tengo hambre
...
En otros idiomas (inglés y hebreo conozco) la edad es diferente y también las sensaciones.

Cuando uno aprende inglés se suele equivocar:
I have cold, I have hungry, similar error en Hebreo.
lo cual literal no se puede,

(Tengo x años. Qué sonrisa tener años?)

¿Por qué se usa el verbo tener?

Comment: El español y el inglés tienen origenes distintos, así que se parte de conceptos, matices distintos.

Answer (score 4):

**Aviso:** Como siempre que se pregunta "*¿por qué...?*" en etimología, no es fácil saber si las afirmaciones de esta respuesta son 100% objetivamente correctas, pero espero que arrojen algo de luz sobre el tema.

En primer lugar, semánticamente, el frío es una *sensación*, y la edad es una *propiedad*, y tanto las sensaciones como las propiedades se *tienen*, lo que justifica el uso de este verbo. Sin embargo, las sensaciones y propiedades también se pueden expresar con (*ser/estar*) + adjetivo, y aquí cada lengua ha tomado una dirección distinta.

El uso del verbo *tener* para expresar la edad y ciertas sensaciones no se limita al español, sino que parece ser común en lenguas provenientes del latín (al menos en italiano y francés):

- Tengo 10 años / Ho 10 anni / J'ai 10 ans.
- Tengo frío / Ho freddo / J'ai froid.

Sin embargo, resulta interesante que (hasta donde yo sé), en latín **no** se usaba el verbo "tener" para estas construcciones. La frase

- Quadraginta annos natus sum. (Tengo cuarenta años)

utiliza el verbo "ser", y "tener frío" es en sí un verbo en latín: *algere*.

La frase "tengo diez años" podría entenderse como una abreviación de:

- Tengo diez años (de edad)

lo que la haría equivalente a otras frases que expresan el valor de una propiedad cuantitativa de un sujeto.

- Tiene 3 metros de altura.

En el caso de "tener frío", solo se utiliza el verbo "tener" para unas pocas sensaciones muy determinadas y muy comunes: *frío, calor, hambre, sed, sueño, prisa, miedo...*, pero no para otras:

- <s>Tengo enojo</s>. Estoy enojado/a.

Solo se me ocurre que la falta de un adjetivo para expresar sensaciones como "frío, calor..." haya llevado a desarrollar expresiones como "tengo frío". La respuesta a la pregunta obvia

- ¿Y por qué no expresiones de otro tipo como "siento frío" (como en inglés) o "me es frío" (como en alemán)?

no la tengo.

Comment: Bueno, el alemán tiene "ich habe Hunger" (tengo hambre), "ich habe Lust" (tengo ganas), "ich habe Angst" (tengo miedo), etc. Cada idioma elige más o menos al tuntún de unas pocas alternativas, parece.